# Path.GetExtension is not working on chrome browser asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
string FileExtn = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fpdDocument.PostedFile.FileName);
```

The above method works fine with the firefox and IE , i am able to view all types of files like zip,txt,xls,xlsx,doc,docx,jpg,png

but when i try to find the extension of file from googlechrome , i failed.

Please any one tell me what is the way to get the actual file extension in google chrome

Comment: You could use a debugger and step through your code? Like inspecting variables and so on?

Comment: It wont work as expected.

Comment: So what is expected? And what does actually happen?

Comment: I tried to find the extension of any file,it works on IE and Firefox but it failed in Chrome.This file upload control is a server side control.